# What is the NuGet package for Azure.Storage.Sas

Tags: c#, azure, nuget

I am looking through its docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.sas?view=azure-dotnet-preview

But don't know how to add it to my project (`dotnet add package ...`)

How can I find out for myself in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your question

> How can I find out for myself in the future?

If you look at the breadcrumb at the top of the page, you see the next level up is 'Client'. Clicking it shows an overview of all namespaces. The next level up is 'Storage', which talks about [Azure Storage APIs for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet-preview). That file explicitly references the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) to use.

Also, clicking on a class tells you which assembly contains that specific class. For instance, the [BlobSasQueryParameters Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.sas.blobsasqueryparameters?view=azure-dotnet-preview) can be found in assembly `Azure.Storage.Blobs.dll`.

If you [Google NuGet Azure.Storage.Blobs.dll](https://www.google.com/search?q=nuget+Azure.Storage.Blobs.dll), you'll find all information you need.

**EDIT:**
As an answer to your question

> What's the point of knowing what assembly it's in

It enables you to craft a pretty specific google query (see above) that helps you get the name of the Nuget package you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

It is referred from the package

**[`WindowsAzure.Storage`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/)**

You need to do with

```
Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Version 9.3.3
```

Comment: I found that but on that page it also said "As of version 9.4.0, this library has been split into multiple parts and replaced"

Comment: yes correct, it depends on that , if you are using Blob you need to use Azure.Storage.Blobs